# Active MQ Scheduled Job Id

Tags: activemq-classic, scheduler

I am using ActiveMQ with Java Spring. I have enabled scheduler and I managed to create scheduled jobs (programmatically). I have also managed to write a method to remove them based on job id. I have been using JmsTemplate to browse a queue, but it only works when the queue has some messages waiting. I can't find job id when the queue is empty.

My question is how am I supposed to get scheduled job id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you want to see what messages are scheduled, so to accomplish that you need to create a Producer that publishes on the Destination named: "ActiveMQ.Scheduler.Management".  Once that's done you create a new Message and set some properties and add a Reply To destination so the scheduler knows where to send your Messages.  Then all you need to do is process the messages with a Consumer that is subscribed to that Reply To destination.

```
    Connection connection = createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // Create the Browse Destination and the Reply To location
    Destination requestBrowse = session.createTopic(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_MANAGEMENT_DESTINATION);
    Destination browseDest = session.createTemporaryQueue();

    // Create the "Browser"
    MessageConsumer browser = session.createConsumer(browseDest);

    connection.start();

    // Send the browse request
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(requestBrowse);
    Message request = session.createMessage();
    request.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION,
                              ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULER_ACTION_BROWSE);
    request.setJMSReplyTo(browseDest);
    producer.send(request);

    Message scheduled = browser.receive(5000);
    while (scheduled != null) {
        // Do something clever...
    }
```

Additional details are documented in [this blog post](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/10/enhanced-jms-scheduler-in-activemq.html).